# How to enable an older version of NGINX ingress for minikube

Tags: nginx, minikube, ingress-controller

I'm pretty sure I'm having issues related to the new 1.0.0 beta version of NGINX ingress controller. I'd like to downgrade to 0.49.0 (or something in the 0. series).

How can I downgrade the NGINX ingress controller version with minikube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do it in a simple way i.e. by choosing the version of **Minikube's** **ingress addon**.

You could either use an older version of **Minikube** which contains [older version of nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases) or instead of enabling it as an addon you can [manually install](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) the version you want.